# Car simulation trouble

Tags: animation, soft-body

My car simulation doesn't work and I don't know what's wrong with her. All modifiers are assigned, maybe I made some mechanical error?
[Video](https://youtu.be/0axRZVXgq-Q)

The car is going to drive over the obstacle on the road.

[image: screenshot 1]

But the soft body on the road is crushed way too early. The car is not even close enough.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Hi. A video is helpful. But 2 additional screenshots and a brief description of the problem would be better to get a quick overview and for the case that your video is unavailable. If the link does not work, the reader does not know what the question is about.

Comment: I would apply the rotation to the obstacle (Ctrl+A > *Apply Rotation* in *Object* mode) and check the car if rotation and scale are applied. The values are displayed in the side panel on the *Item* tab in the *Transform* section. Rotation should be 0°, 0°, 0° and scale 1.0, 10. 1.0.

Comment: If the car doesn't have physics property it won't influence the simulation. It looks like the cloth falls by the gravity. You can turn it off in the Scene Properties or disable its influence in the Cloth Physics (Field Weights).

Comment: @Blunderyes, that's right. I had a value of rotate 90 0 and 210. When I set everything to 0, it turned out like this)). Can I somehow remap the keys, or have I installed the wrong car model? [screen](https://imgur.com/a/Pc4l2Xe)

Comment: @FFeller rigid body, or what phys modifier?

Comment: If you don't want to influence the car's movement by physics, the collision is probably better choice.

Comment: @FFeller car just destroy it and does not move on the surface. Maybe you need some parameters for the collision [screen](https://imgur.com/a/Y1J5Soq)